# Sencha Touch 2 set label in Controller

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm new to the MVC structure with Sencha Touch 2.

In my view, I have a label as follows:

> {
>                           xtype: 'label',
>                           itemId: 'title',
>                           html: 'title'
>                       }

In my controller, how do I set the value of this label?

Currently my controller (working off a tutorial sample):

> Ext.define("NotesApp.controller.Notes", {
>
> ```
> extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
> config: {
>     refs: {
>         // We're going to lookup our views by xtype.
>         noteView: "noteview",
>         noteEditorView: "noteeditorview",
>         notesList: "#notesList"
>     },
>     control: {
>         noteView: {
>             // The commands fired by the notes list container.
>             noteNextCommand: "onNoteNextCommand",
>             noteAnswerCommand: "onNoteAnswerCommand"
>         },
>         noteEditorView: {
>             // The commands fired by the note editor.
>             saveNoteCommand: "onSaveNoteCommand",
>             deleteNoteCommand: "onDeleteNoteCommand",
>             backToHomeCommand: "onBackToHomeCommand"
>         }
>
>     }
> },
>
> onNoteNextCommand: function () {
>        var noteView = this.getNoteView();           
>        console.log("loaded view"); 
>        //set label here                  
> },
> // Base Class functions.
> launch: function () {
>     this.callParent(arguments);
>     var notesStore = Ext.getStore("Notes");
>     notesStore.load();
>     console.log("launch");
> },
> init: function () {
>     this.callParent(arguments);
>     console.log("init");
> } });
> ```

The full View code:

> Ext.define("NotesApp.view.Note", {
>       extend: "Ext.Container",
>       alias: "widget.noteview",
>
> ```
> config: {
>     layout: {
>         type: 'fit'
>     },
>     items: [
>             {
>             xtype: "toolbar",
>             title: "Random Question",
>             docked: "top",
>             items: [
>                     { xtype: 'spacer' },
>                     {
>                         xtype: "button",
>                         text: 'List',
>                         ui: 'action',
>                         itemId: "list"
>                     }
>                     ]
>             },
>             {                
>                     xtype: "label",
>                     html: 'question',                        
>                     itemId: "question"                        
>             },
>             {                
>                     xtype: "label",
>                     html: 'answer',                        
>                     itemId: "answer"                        
>             }
>             ],
>     listeners: [{
>                 delegate: "#list",
>                 event: "tap",
>                 fn: "onListTap"
>                 }, 
>                 {
>                 delegate: "#question",
>                 event: "tap",
>                 fn: "onQuestionTap"
>                 },
>                 {
>                 delegate: "#answer",
>                 event: "tap",
>                 fn: "onAnswerTap"
>                 }]
> },    
> onListTap: function () {
>     console.log("list");
>     this.fireEvent("showList", this);
> },
> onQuestionTap: function () {
>     console.log("noteAnswer");
>     this.fireEvent('noteAnswer', this);
> },
> onAnswerTap: function () {
>     console.log("noteNext");
>     this.fireEvent('noteNext', this);
> } });
> ```

Comment: might need to see the code of your controller too

Comment: i added the controller code. thanks!

Comment: basically I want the answer-label to show answer when tapped on the question-label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to your label in your controller :

```
config: {
  refs: {
    yourlabel : #YOUR_LABEL_ID'
  }
  …
}
```

and then in your controller you can access the label by calling `this.getYourlabel();`

So, in order to change the title, you need to do (wherever you want in your controller)

```
this.getYourlabel().setHtml('Label');
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Give your label some `id` property value

```
{                
  xtype: "label",
  html: 'answer',                        
  id: "answerLabel"                        
}
```

and then write the following code in your `controller`.

```
.....
..... // Controller code ..
refs: {
     answerLabel: '#answerLabel',
    },
control: {
     answerLabel: {
       tap: 'answerLabelFn'
     }
}
.....
.....
answerLabelFn : function() {
      // Your Label tap handler code...
}
```