# How to change the label value which is inside a controller in Sencha?

Tags: sencha-touch, label, sencha-touch-2

I have two labels inside a container. When i am clicking some button, i want to change the label value. I tried with many ways. But it is not changing.

Here is my view code:

```
   Ext.define('MortgageCalculator.view.CalculateScreen', {
    extend : 'Ext.Panel',

    config : {
        scrollable : true,
        items : [{
            xtype : 'titlebar',
            docked : 'top',
            ui : 'green',
            title : 'MORTGAGE CALCULATOR'
        }, {

            xtype : 'container',
            layout : {
                type : 'vbox'
            },
items : [{

xtype : 'button',
                name : 'submitbtn',
                text : 'Calculate Monthly',
                ui : 'confirm',
                width: 200,
                height : 40,
                margin : 'auto'
            }, {

                xtype : 'container',
                id:'capandintsum',
                layout : {
                    type : 'hbox'
                },
                items : [{
                    xtype : 'label',
                    layout : 'fit',
                    html : 'Capital & Interest',
                    flex : 1,
                    margin : '60 0 0 20'
                }, {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    layout : 'fit',
                    name:'cap&int',
                    id : 'cap&int',
                    html : '0',
                    flex : 1,
                    margin : '60 0 0 20'
                }]
            },

            {
                xtype : 'container',
                layout : {
                    type : 'hbox'
                },
                items : [{
                    xtype : 'label',
                    layout : 'fit',
                    html : 'Interest Only',
                    flex : 1,
                    margin : '20 0 0 20'
                }, {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    layout : 'fit',
                    name:'intonly',
                    id : 'intonly',
                    html : '0',
                    flex : 1,
                    margin : '20 0 0 20'
                }]
        }]
    }
});
```

And for the controller i am using the below code:

```
Ext.define('MortgageCalculator.controller.Calculate', {         
        extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
        config : {
            refs : {
                submitbtn : 'button[name=submitbtn]',
                capandintlbl : '#intonly'
                // capandintlbl :  '#cap&int', 
                // onlyintlbl : '#intonly' 
            },
            control : {
                submitbtn : {
                    tap : 'onSubmitButtonTap'
                },
            }
        },


        onSubmitButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {
                                this.getCapandintlbl.setHtml('hello, it is changed');           }



    })
```

Please help..

Comment: getCapandintlbl is a function. So use this.getCapandintlbl() to access the capandintlbl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i able to make in this way:

```
var me = this; 
var labelfield = me.getCapandintlbl(); 
labelfield.setHtml('it is changing');
```

Thanks Rachel..

Answer (score 1):

For just setting a value for label , you can use setText method described in label

see [this link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Label-method-setText)

```
 yourLabel.setText('value');
```

Comment: giving the error:: Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
   a.push.apply(a, arguments);
   return c.apply(b || this, a)
  } has no method 'setText'

Comment: weird. will do some more research, what version are you using?

Comment: Actually as it is not the child of the top container, it is not able to get the reference.

Comment: try getCapandintlbl.labelEl.setHTML([your hmtl stuff])

Comment: again error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setHTML' of undefined

Comment: did you put this. before it?

Comment: apparently if you require Ext.data.JsonP to be loaded you don't get that error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23037/discussion-between-arindam-mukherjee-and-rachel-gallen)

Comment: If i am removing the container and using the setHtml(), it is changing the text..But after keeping the container, it is not coming..

Comment: how odd. i wonder what the workaround is? do you really need the container?

Comment: can you tell me how i can make the two labels horizontally without container??

Comment: see this link it might answer your question http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?207999-Set-custom-label-for-the-textfield-which-is-inside-the-container

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679175/sencha-touch-2-set-label-in-controller